# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' Xamarin Spinner Array from Json API

Tags: arrays, json, api, xamarin, spinner

Im facing issue when filling spinner array, it said invalid cast.
could you help me to solve this issue ?

```
private async void getplant()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost/VMSAPINEW2/MasterData/getplantlist";
        JsonValue json = await FetchWeatherAsync(url);
        string temp = "";
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < json.Count; i++)
        {
            temp = json[i]["plantName"].ToString();
            items.Add(temp);
        }

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, (IList<string>)items);
        spinnerPlantNormal.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

The result from **item** is

```
item[0] "\"SBM - BIKE\""
item[1] "\"SBM - ROD\""
```

and the error
**System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'** when filling adapter with array.

Comment: instead of `(IList<string>)items` try doing `items.Cast<string>().ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to chanage

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
```